# Oracle RAC : Unable to import .DMP files in DB using IMP or IMPDP commands

Tags: oracle, datapump

I am trying to import .dmp files into my oracle 11g DB.

I set below ENV varables, and then I am trying to run imp and impdp commands, but I am getting below errors.

Can anyone help me here? What are the possible errors in importing dmp files to RAC DB and solutions for those?

```
ENV variables i set

export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib
export ORACLE_SID=orcl

Error Trace------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[uimuser@blr2261783 bin]$ imp

Import: Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production on Tue Mar 12 06:08:28 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Username: sys
Password:

IMP-00058: ORACLE error 1034 encountered
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
IMP-00005: all allowable logon attempts failed
IMP-00000: Import terminated unsuccessfully
[uimuser@blr2261783 bin]$
```

Answer (score 1):

Try sqlplus first.

Probably orcl is not the SID but orcl1 or orcl2. Do a :

```
select * from v$instance
```

and set ORACLE_SID to the instance_name on the server where you start impdp

Answer (score 1):

I had the same errors on Linux Oracle 11g using impdp.
I had an incorrect ORACLE_SID env on Linux where in my case it needed to be `case sensitive`.

So in my case I had to use:

`ORACLE_SID=mysid`

instead of

`ORACLE_SID=MYSID`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your environement variables are not set correctly or that your server is not running. 
Check:

- Your server is running on the same machine

  Server has the *same* ORACLE_HOME - check there is no trailing slash on ORACLE_HOME